Using DI with Classes that have Base Classes
I'm still trying to understand C# and how DI works with base classes.  Here's the example I have.
I have a setup of classes that all bring down a Base class that sets up initial configurations.  I'm not too good on the understanding of how to have these classes have an interface while also having inheritance.  I'll show what I'm looking at.
public abstract class BaseSetupClass
{
  private IConfiguration _config;
  protected BaseSetupClass(IConfiguration config)
  {
    // Do a bunch of configuration stuff
  }
}

public class SomeActor(IConfiguration config, ILogger<SomeActor> logger) : BaseSetupClass(config)
{
  // Do some other stuff here
}

I am used to needing interfaces and setting up DI in the Program.cs file like this:
builder.Services.AddTransiant<ISomeActor, SomeActor>();

Is there a better way of setting up things with DI here?

IMHO follow the options pattern instead of reading raw configuration in every class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Although it's generally a good practice to develop to an interface, .NET DI doesn't necessarily require the existence of an interface.
The AddTransient method has an overload that accepts one generic argument only, so you can use it with if you don't wish to register the abstraction of your type.
builder.Services.AddTransiant<SomeActor>();

Make sure that:

All dependencies of SomeActor are also registered
You are using the right service life time (Transiant/Scoped/Singlton)


I have always used interfaces with anything I put into the DI Services. using GetRequiredService<> with the interface allows for different concrete implementations of an interface for different applications that share service libraries. Another use case is when you need to mock something for testing. The test project sets up the DI Container with mocked repositories, etc., whereas the application(s) use real databases, repos, etc.
